# Parse Javascript promises on builtin functions

Tags: javascript, ios, asynchronous, parse-platform, promise

Im trying to send a push message to everyone with read access every time a new note is saved. This is the code I've been trialing. Before I was experience a can't serialise objects this was because I was using asynchronous calls. After doing a bit more research I stumbled across javascript promises. I've never used something like this before so i'm finding it difficult to get my head around it.

The problem I'm finding is that object.getACL() is an asynchronous call. I tried first just adding a .then after it but this returned method not found. Now I've tried to create it as its own function and manually make a new promise and resolve the promise after it returns. This isn't working either. I just need the function to sequential call one after another, like normal programming lol.

In pseudocode it should get the ACL. Evaluate each member in the ACL and return an array of all users with read access. Then send a push notification to each member. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Notes", function(request) {
    var idsToSend = [];
    var i = 0;
    console.log("start");

    var getACL = function(object) {
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();
        console.log("enter getACL");
        var noteACL = object.getACL() {
            promise.resolve(noteACL);
        };
        return promise;
    };

    getACL(request.object).then(function(objACL) {
        var ACLinJSON = objACL.toJSON();
        for (var key in ACLinJSON) {
            if (ACLinJSON[key].read == "true") {
                idsToSend[i] = key.id;
                console.log("i = " + i + " = " + idsToSend[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
        console.log(idsToSend);

        //lookup installations
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.containedIn('user', idsToSend);
        Parse.Push.send({
            where: query,
            data: {
                alert: "note updated"
            }
        }, {
            success: function() {
                console.log("Success sent push");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error("can’t find user"); //error
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Seems like there's something wrong with this line `var noteACL = object.getACL() {`

Comment: yeh that was my last experimentation. I did have it as a separate function outside the after save function but that didn't work either. How can i get object.getACL() to trigger after it returns

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually not familiar with parse.com api, I just thought it was weird having a `{` after a function call. Also you have this `if (ACLinJSON[key].read = "true")` should be `==` or `===`. You should probably run your code through http://jshint.com/ and fix the errors.

Comment: Cheers i'll use that from now on. I'm not too concerned about the inner code i'm really trying to just get everything to execute sequentially after the object.getACL() is returned. I have no idea with the concept behind promises. I've tried understanding the examples on the net but can't comprehend it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ParseObject.getACL()`](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#getACL) is **not** an async call, it returns a `Parse.ACL` not a `Parse.Promise`, why bother using a promise for this? You're needlessly complicating your code.

Remove the Promises, just get the ACL and loop through the JSON, and if you still have problems, post a new question with the issues you then have.

Comment: Thanks I've tried that and I have no idea why it's not executed in order. I've posted a new question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114339/parse-cloudcode-order-of-execution) any help would be appreciated