# Parse CloudCode order of execution

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, parse-platform

Im trying to send a push message to everyone with read access every time a new note is saved.

In pseudocode it should get the ACL. Evaluate each member in the ACL and return an array of all users with read access. Then send a push notification to each member.

I've tried running separate task one by one and it works properly. However when I put everything together in the following code I get strange results. Looking at the log I can see it not executing in order as I expect. I first though the getACL call was an asynchronous call so I tried to implement promises with no luck. Then after help from stackoverflow I find out that getACL is not asynchronous therefore the code should just work, right?

This is what I'm trying:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Notes", function(request) {
    var idsToSend = [];
    var i = 0;
    console.log("1 start");

    var objACL = request.object.getACL();
    var ACLinJSON = objACL.toJSON();
    console.log("2 ACL = " + ACLinJSON);

    for (var key in ACLinJSON) {
        if (ACLinJSON[key].read == "true") {
            idsToSend[i] = key.id;
            console.log("3 i = " + i + " = " + idsToSend[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }


    console.log("4 idsToSend = " + idsToSend);

    //lookup installations
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.containedIn('user', idsToSend);
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: query,
        data: {
            alert: "note updated"
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            console.log("Success sent push");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("can’t find user"); //error
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the response I see from parse log

```
I2014-08-04T08:08:06.708Z]4 idsToSend =
I2014-08-04T08:08:06.712Z]2 ACL = [object Object]
I2014-08-04T08:08:06.714Z]1 start
I2014-08-04T08:08:06.764Z]Success sent push
```

Everything is completely out of order??

How can I execute the above function in the way it's written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the logs are not in order when I run things too, could be a timing issue or something, ignore the order when they're in the same second, I have done other tests to confirm things really do run in order on my own Cloud Code... had me completely confused for a while there.

The issue you're having is that log #3 is never being hit... try tracing `ACLinJSON` on it's own to see the actual structure. When you append it to a string it outputs `[object Object]` as you have seen, so do `console.log(ACLinJSON);` instead.

Here's the structure I've seen:

```
{
  "*":{"read":true},
  "Administrator":{"write":true}
}
```

Based on that I would expect your loop to work, but it may have a different level of wrapping.

UPDATE:

Turns out the issue was looking for the string "true" instead of a boolean true, thus the fix is to replace the following line:

```
// replace this: if (ACLinJSON[key].read == "true") {
if (ACLinJSON[key].read == true) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I couldn't get over the log not coming in in order but after you said that's just how it is I looked beyond that problem and discovered in my if statement I should only use single = sign. Is this a javascript thing?

Comment: Using a single `=` will do an assignment and return the value assigned (which will evaluate to a "thruthy" answer). Definitely keep using `==` when you want to compare values!

Comment: That's what I thought but after looking at the output and visually checking that it was indeed true a double = didn't work. Can you do a straight compare like that on strings?

Comment: Yes you can. Try adding a `console.log(ACLinJSON[key]);` just before your `if` statement and see what the string value is, perhaps also log the value of `ACLinJSON[key].read` too, more logs the better when trying to debug!

Comment: Ok sorted it. I thought when looking at JSON structures everything is strings. However I found this was not true so removing the inverted commas sorted my issue. Thanks for all your help